# $\theta_1(\theta_1 + 1)x^\theta_1 = \theta_2(\theta_2 + 1)x^{\theta_2} \Rightarrow \theta_1 = \theta_2$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, functions

Let's fix number $x \in (0, 1)$. I want to prove for $\theta_1, \theta_2 > 0$ that:

$$\theta_1(\theta_1 + 1)x^\theta_1 = \theta_2(\theta_2 + 1)x^{\theta_2} \Rightarrow \theta_1 = \theta_2$$

I wanted to assume that $\theta_1 \neq \theta_2$. Then without loosing of generality we can assume that $\theta_1>\theta_2$. Then we can say that $\exists_{\epsilon>0}:\theta_1 =\theta_2 + \epsilon$ and rewrite expression as:

$$(\theta_2 + \epsilon)(\theta_2 +  \epsilon + 1 )x^\epsilon = \theta_2(\theta_2 + 1)$$

$$(1 + \frac{\epsilon}{\theta_2})(1 + \frac{\epsilon}{\theta_2 + 1})x^\epsilon = 1$$

But I couldn't find any contradiction. Could you please give me a hint how can I prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $$f(x;\theta) = \theta(\theta+1)x^\theta, \quad 0 \le x \le 1, \quad \theta > 0.$$  Then if your question is whether $$\bigl(f(x;\theta_1) = f(x;\theta_2) \quad \forall x \in [0,1]\bigr) \implies \theta_1 = \theta_2, \tag{1}$$ then the answer is yes.  If however, your question is whether for a single given $x \in [0,1]$, if $f(x;\theta_1) = f(x;\theta_2)$, then $\theta_1 = \theta_2$, the answer is no; e.g., $$f(\sqrt{3/10}; 2) = f(\sqrt{3/10}; 4) = \frac{9}{5}.$$

How do we prove the assertion $(1)$?  We reason by contradiction.  Suppose $\theta_1 \ne \theta_2$ and for all $x \in [0,1]$, $f(x;\theta_1) = f(x;\theta_2)$.  Then this implies
$$\frac{f(x;\theta_1)}{f(x;\theta_2)} = \frac{\theta_1(\theta_1 + 1)}{\theta_2(\theta_2 + 1)} x^{\theta_1 - \theta_2} = 1$$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.  Equivalently, this implies
$$x^m = c$$ for some nonzero constants $m = \theta_1 - \theta_2$ and $c > 0$.  But this has the unique solution $x = c^{1/m}$, which of course cannot equal all values in $[0,1]$.  Therefore, no such $\theta_1, \theta_2$ exist.